# Template instantiation in case of multilevel inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, multi-level

I am still in the process of learning C++. This is my scenario.
I have three classes. The topmost base class is templated.
The middle class which derives from the base is templated too.
The derived (Concrete class) which I intend to use inherits the midddle class.
I explicitly instantiate the  Middle class. However, the complier throws an error each time saying
that the Base class is undefined. How do I instantiate the Middle class in a way such that 
the base class is fully defined?

Here is the overview of how these classes are defined:

TopBase.h

```
template <class T>
class TopBase
{
   typedef typename T::Concrete Concrete;
}
```

Middle.h

```
template <class T>
class Middle : public TopBase<T> 
{
   typedef typename T::Concrete Concrete;
}
Middle() : TopBase<T>() {}
```

Concrete.h

```
struct TConcrete {
static int x;
typedef Concrete instance;
}


class Concrete :
   public Middle<TConcrete>
{
}
```

Comment: Are you including the header that includes the definition of the base types?

Comment: You're missing the `;` after the class definitions.

Comment: You should also show your includes. It could be that you need a forward declaration of one of your class somewhere

Comment: Also, the line `Middle() : TopBase<T>() {}` outside of the class definition will result in a parse error too.

Comment: DyP - I actually has that in my code. Forgot to put them here.

Comment: David - Spot on. I cannot believe that after scraching my head for an hour it was this. Missing a header file inclusion. Cant believe I wasted so much time for this

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your typedef Concrete instance, because Concrete typename is used while instantiating Middle.

```
template <class T>
class TopBase
{
   typedef typename T::Concrete Concrete;
};

template <class T>
class Middle : public TopBase<T> 
{
public:
    Middle() : TopBase<T>() {}
    typedef typename T::Concrete Concrete;
};

class ConcreteX;

struct TConcrete {
  static int x;
  typedef ConcreteX Concrete; // <-- here was an error
};

class ConcreteX :
   public Middle<TConcrete>
{
};
```